# Why does my Windows 10 laptop create multiple network adapters (using a USB dongle)?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, usb, device-manager

I have to go into Device Manager and clear out the hidden network adapters every month or so because 25% of the time when I plug in my USB Gigabit (Startech) Ethernet dongle, my Windows 10 laptop creates a new network.

Why would this be? What are the criteria Windows looks at when To or NOT TO create a new network adapter? How can I make it stop?

Comment: Do you plug it into the same port each time or different ones?  Its possible that plugging it into a different USB port would make Windows believe its a different device and install it once more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I plug it in the same port but will make sure I do that.